# How to create a page that can be unlocked with a code

Tags: python, css, django, forms, model

So basically I want to create a page that is locked, and the only way to unlock it is by entering a specific code.

So far the only thing that I know is that there will be a database of codes. Whatever input the user enters will be compared with the codes in the database, and if there is a match the user will be granted access.

The idea is to allow users into a payment gateway only if they have specific code.

I have no clue how to go on about it. Would I be able to use some prebuilt functions in Django? If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be nice.

Comment: I did not get `specific code`? Do you want to store them? If yes then I don't think it's a good idea. The best way is to generate within views and send the link or otp whichever you are using.

Comment: The codes are a bit like a serial key in a game. The codes can only be used once, and I must know which code has been burned.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3 things:

1. A database running on a server. (Eg. MySQL with phpMyAdmin)
2. Server-side python code which can take requests and interface with the database locally. (So you don't have to expose your DB to the internet)
3. Client-side django which sends the code to the server-side python in order to check the code against the database.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have almost a full functioning website running on Python/Django. It has user accounts, image/video upload ability, entry posts. and etc. So I want to do this on python/django if possible.